# wrong answer with equation in assembly

Tags: assembly, floating-point, equation, pi

I am trying to implement a equation in assembly with floting points and it it is giving me the wrong answer.

i put it in a caculater and it gives me 433.0127018... and with my code i get 0.0193269641235 the answer is not even close to correct but i cant find out why it is giving the wrong aswer.

formula:

```
initX=sin((degree+ (i∗dStep)) ∗pi/180) ∗ scale
```

variables:

```
degree      dd  0
dStep       dq  120.0   
scale       dq  500.0
pi          dq  3.14159265358979    
oneEighty   dq  180.0
initX       dq  0.0
tmp         dq  0.0
tmptmpdegree    dq  0.0
```

code:

```
;  initX=sin((degree+(i*dstep))*pi/180)*scale

movsxd  r10,dword[degree]
cvtsi2sd    xmm0,r10
movsd   qword[tmpdegree],xmm0
movsd   xmm1,qword[pi]
divss   xmm1,dword[oneEighty]
movsd   qword[tmp],xmm1

movsd   xmm0,qword[tmpdegree]
addsd   xmm0,qword[dStep]
mulsd   xmm0,qword[tmp]
call    sin
mulsd   xmm0,qword[scale]
movsd   qword[initX],xmm0
```

Comment: You forgot `i`. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

[`divss` is single-precision](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIVSS.html), and you used it on double-precision data.  You even wrote `dword [oneEighty]`, even though you put a `dq` float constant at that label.

So you're treating the low 32bits of the mantissa of the `double`s as a `float`.

Like Jester says, a debugger would have shown you that the value in `xmm1` didn't change to what you'd expect after that instruction.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links.

---

Even better would be to combine the two constants at assemble time, by only storing `pi/180.0` so you don't need to divide at all.  Remember, *you* are the compiler.  If you want your code to not suck, you have to find ways to simplify it yourself.

---

Also, this is pointless:

```
movsd   qword[tmp], xmm1
...
mulsd   xmm0, qword[tmp]
```

Nothing between those instructions will clobber xmm1, so you should just leave the value in xmm1.

Same for `tmpdegree`.  You should just `cvtsi2sd  xmm0, [degree]` when you're ready for it.

You should also take `degree` as an arg in a register, instead of a global.  And you have your constants mixed in with your variables.  Put your constants in the `.rodata` section.